# Parsing json in csv in pandas not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I have this data:

```
#my.csv
"accountid","configuration"
"797847293","{'dBInstanceIdentifier': 'grafanadb', 'dBInstanceClass': 'db.t3.micro', 'engine': 'postgres', 'dBInstanceStatus': 'available'}"
```

How can I bring into format like:

```
# result.csv
accountid,dBInstanceIdentifier,dbInstanceClass,engine
797847293,grafanadb,db.t3.micro,engine
```

I tried it with python pandas, but not result so far respectively errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: You will have to load the data and write an algorithm to transform the data as you wish, then write to the result.csv.

Comment: are you missing an extra `"` at the end of the second line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the csv to dataframe and convert `configuration` to dict with `ast.literal_eval`. Then use `pd.json_normalize` to convert a column of dictionary into columns.

```py
import ast

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', quotechar='"')

out = pd.concat([df['accountid'], pd.json_normalize(df['configuration'].apply(ast.literal_eval))], axis=1)
```

```
print(out)

   accountid dBInstanceIdentifier dBInstanceClass    engine dBInstanceStatus
0  797847293            grafanadb     db.t3.micro  postgres        available
```

Comment: Perfect, that is what I was looking for. I could reduce my code a lot. 
Could be so easy to make the manager happy xD

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've gotten this csv file from some data source, it shouldn't be this inconsistent in its formatting and should have a double quote `"` at the end of the second line which I believe you've missed out when copying over. Like this:

```
#my.csv
"accountid","configuration"
"797847293","{'dBInstanceIdentifier': 'grafanadb', 'dBInstanceClass': 'db.t3.micro', 'engine': 'postgres', 'dBInstanceStatus': 'available'}"
```

If that is the case, you can simply specify the `quotechar` argument in `pd.read_csv` to tell it to ignore delimiters inside the double quotes `"`

```
df = pd.read_csv('a.csv', quotechar='"')
```

You can then do your processing in pandas before writing back into csv from here.